# Calculating the area between 2 curves

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

I need to find the area restricted between $y=\frac{2}{x}$ , $y=x+1$ and $x=3$. Sounds fairly simple. However, something isn't working out here.

I have plotted the functions:

[image]

And tried setting up integrals, in this way:

$\int_{-2}^{0}(x+1-\frac{2}{x})dx+\int_{0}^{1}(x+1)dx+\int_{1}^{3}\frac{2}{x}dx$

This gives infinity, exactly like the plot suggests. The answer in the book is $6-2ln(3)$

How can it be ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area $ = \int_{1}^{3} \left[(x+1) - \frac{2}{x}\right]dx$

A $ = \left[\frac{x^2}{2} + x - 2ln(x)\right]|_1^3$
If you evaluate , it gives $6-2ln(3)$

You have to calculate the area bounded by all three curves ( not any two)